# How to snap jQuery UI draggable back to grid correctly after moving freely with no snapping

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

Using jQuery UI, I have some draggable DIVs. The DIVs snap to a 32x32 grid using the corresponding option grid: [32, 32].

The user can move around the DIVs in the grid but he can also hold down the Alt key to move them freely without snapping to the grid. When the Alt key is held down, I simply change the grid option to [1, 1] for that DIV.

Problem is that the next time that DIV is going to be moved, it will be aligned to a [32,32] grid but there will be an offset.

So what I need to do is:

- DIV is dragged around on a 32,32 grid
- User presses Alt and now instance is moved freely in a 1,1 grid
- User places the DIV somewhere in an uneven coordinate like (103, 67)
- Next time the DIV is dragged, first snap it correctly on the 32,32
  grid and then start dragging (unless of course the user is pressing
  Alt)

http://jsfiddle.net/SwHpa/2/ (ALT key doesn't work quite fluidly in this fiddle, you have to click on the empty space while holding ALT then drag the DIV to test free dragging)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".draggable").draggable({
        grid: [32, 32]
    });
});

$(window).on('keydown', function(event){

    if (event.keyCode == 18) {
         $(".draggable").draggable({
            grid: [2, 2]
        });
    }

});

$(window).on('keyup', function(event){

    if (event.keyCode == 18) {
         $(".draggable").draggable({
            grid: [32, 32]
        });
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm new to stack overflow, first time ever commenting but maybe something like this would help: http://jsfiddle.net/SwHpa/4/

```
var myTop = jQuery(".draggable").css("top");
var myLeft = jQuery(".draggable").css("left");
var myNewTop = 0;
var myNewLeft = 0;
myNewTop = Math.floor(myTop / 32) * 32;
myNewLeft = Math.floor(myLeft / 32) * 32;
jQuery(".draggable").css({"top" : myNewTop, "left" : myNewLeft});
```

After you let go of the alt key, you'll need to re-calculate to the nearest "32" increment. I figured if you take your current top/left and divide it by 32, then Math.floor it to the nearest whole number and finally multiply it against 32 you'll be right back into the square boxes.